# Hard limit connections Spring Boot

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jetty, undertow

I'm working on a simple micro service written in Spring Boot. This service will act as a proxy towards another resources that have a hard concurrent connection limit and the requests take a while to process.

I would like to impose a hard limit on concurrent connections allowed to my micro service and rejecting any with either a 503 or on tcp/ip level. I've tried to look into different configurations that can be made for Jetty/Tomcat/Undertow but haven't figured out yet something completely convincing.

I found some settings regulating thread pools:

- server.tomcat.max-threads=0 # Maximum amount of worker threads.
- server.undertow.io-threads= # Number of I/O threads to create for the worker.
- server.undertow.worker-threads= # Number of worker threads.
- server.jetty.acceptors= # Number of acceptor threads to use.
- server.jetty.selectors= # Number of selector threads to use.

But if understand correctly these are all configuring thread pool sizes and will just result in connections being queued on some level.

This seems like really interesting, but this hasn't been merged in yet and is targeted for Spring Boot 1.5 , https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/6571

Am I out of luck using a setting for now? I could of course implement a filter but would rather block it on an earlier level and not have to reinvent the wheel. I guess using apache or something else in front is also an option, but still that feels like an overkill.

Comment: Jetty has a `QoSFilter` and `DoSFilter` for these kinds of connection limits (Upcoming Jetty 9.4.x will have more options).

Comment: I have looked at DoSFilter but I can't find any parameter that actually limits number of parallell/ongoing requests. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at [EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer.html)

[this gist](https://gist.github.com/joshlong/10964238) could give you and idea how to do that.

```
TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = ...;
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector ->
            ((AbstractProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxConnections(10000));
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out as soon as I have time, but looks promising.